# Inserting PHP variables into MySQL database using foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an array: `$product_counts = array_count_values($product_array);`

The keys for this array are merchant ID's and the values are integers (product counts). So if I was to write the following code:

```
foreach($product_counts as $key => $value){
    echo "key: $key";
    echo "value: $value";
        }
```

I would get the following (which is what I want):

```
key: 26816928 value: 13
key: 26816931 value: 2 ... 
X the amount of indexes in the array.
```

However if I was to write the following code:

```
foreach($product_counts as $key => $value){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO merchantinfo(ProductCount) VALUES $value WHERE MerchantID = $key"); 
}
```

The values of the $value variable don't go into the field where MerchantID = $key....instead the tuples just default to null, which is what I've set them to do. I believe this could be a case of needing to type cast the variable as integers .... but I'm in general quite lost with this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use a where clause in an insert statement. I think you want to use update instead.

```
mysql_query("update merchantinfo set ProductCount= $value WHERE MerchantID = $key");
```

Comment: I now feel exceptionally idiotic. however thanks a lot! Complete star.

Comment: @user1703085 We all make silly mistakes every now and again. Part of life :) If anything, I am willing to be you will *never* again make this one hehe. Pass it on and help the next chap out there!

Comment: I vow to pass on such wisdom! What an excellent start ... I only joined this community 5 minutes ago and I'm already kicking myself for not joining years ago!

Answer (score 2):

Take values in () too, like:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

And in your case you must use `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT`

```
UPDATE merchantinfo SET ProductCount = $value WHERE MerchantID = $key
```

Comment: This will just insert rows into the database, not update the correct row (as implied with the `where` clause the OP is trying to use).

Comment: Agree, I simple didn't complete my answer yet :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to update value not insert:
That should work for you:

```
$query = "UPDATE merchantinfo set ProductCount='$value' WHERE MerchantID='$key'";
```

If you want insert new row then:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO merchantinfo(ProductCount,MerchantID) VALUES('$value','$key')";
```

Anyway would be much better to use PDO and prepare statement (at least safer)

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE merchantinfo set ProductCount=? WHERE MerchantID=?");
foreach($product_counts as $key => $value){
    $stmt->execute(array($value, $key));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional feedback, it's much appreciated!